# Transparency Through Parent Div Containers

Tags: javascript, css, html, transparent

Say you have a box with a background, that starts with white and ends in black. Alright, now say there's a smaller box inside that box. Now, there's an even smaller box inside that smaller box. Again, a smaller box inside the previous box.

In this situation, the boxes are Divs. I want the background of the smallest div to reflect the background of the largest div. Since the background of the largest div is a gradient, I can't just slap the same gradient on the background of the smallest div. I've got to somehow make the 2 parent divs transparent in the areas that the smallest div covers. Any way to achieve this?

***P.S.** Sorry if the question is a bit confusing. Writing it a bit hurriedly.*

Comment: I think the only way you can achieve this is by using an image.

Comment: You can use transparent colors in gradients

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `background:transparent;` to the smaller box in `style` attribute.